# how to enable registrations after admin approval in asp.net C#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three types of Registrations

1.Doctor Registration
2.Patient Registration
3.Agent Registration

Now the admin has to approve & enable the Doctor & Agent registrations...

After approval of Admin only the the user can login into his profiles

Comment: what is your exact question?? Is it related with programming or business logic?

Comment: This question is far too wide to just give a short answer to. Are you using a membership provider of some sort? Have you built the logic from scratch yourself?

Comment: This question is about programming...

Comment: i already developed both the registrations and login;s. Now the Requirement of my client is Admin has to approve the registration then only user get login into his page

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have created an User Table having login details of Doctor and Agent users.
So in same table have a column of type bit field and its name can be IsApproved.

In admin section provide form where admin can see the details and change the status of IsApproved.

In login form check whether username and password are matching with the record and if yes then its IsApproved columns's value shouold be true.If not then show appropriate message.